# How to vertical align Div's elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS codes. The second row should be horizontal, but I don't understand why the second row is not horizontal. Please help me make the second row horizontal and align the elements of the  tag vertically.

**CSS**

```
#kafel {

   font-size:15px;
   color: #358dd5;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-align: center;
   display: table;
}

#kafel1 {
    width:183px;
    height:183px;
    margin-right:20px !important;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
    border:10px solid white;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

#kafel1:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;
}

#kafel2 {
    width:183px;
    height:183px;
    margin-right:20px !important;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
    border:10px solid white;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

#kafel2:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;
}

#kafel3 {
    width:183px;
    height:183px;
    margin-right:20px !important;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:green;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
    border:10px solid white;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;

}

#kafel3:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Studia 1 st</h3>

<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Socjologia</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Kulturoznawstwo</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Informatyka społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Socjologia 2st</h3>
<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">E-gospodarka</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">Innowacje i interwencje społeczne</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">Multimedia i komunikacja społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Kulturoznawstwo 2st</h3>
<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Komunikacja wizualna i projektowanie graficzne</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Ochrona dóbr natury i kultury</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Projektowanie graficzne w kulturze nowych mediów</div></a>
</div>
```

The output has been pasted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kapka1a/6hcoejtn/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use same `id` multiple times in a single web page. Use `class` instead.

Use `.kafel a {display: inline-block;}` with some other properties as mentioned below and this problem will be solved.

```css
body {
 background: #ccc;
}
.kafel {
   color: #358dd5;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: -4px;
   font-size: 0;
}

.kafel a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:15px;
}

.kafel1 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  display: table-cell !important;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%; 
}

.kafel1:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#358dd5; 
}

.kafel2 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

.kafel2:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #358dd5;
}

.kafel3 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:green;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  display: table-cell !important;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

.kafel3:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#358dd5;
}
```

```html
<h3>Studia 1 st</h3>

<div class="kafel">
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel1">Socjologia</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel1">Kulturoznawstwo</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel1">Informatyka społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Socjologia 2st</h3>
<div class="kafel">
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel2">E-gospodarka</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel2">Innowacje i interwencje społeczne</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel2">Multimedia i komunikacja społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Kulturoznawstwo 2st</h3>
<div class="kafel">
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel3">Komunikacja wizualna i projektowanie graficzne</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel3">Ochrona dóbr natury i kultury</div></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div class="kafel3">Projektowanie graficzne w kulturze nowych mediów</div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
<h3>Studia 1 st</h3>

<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Socjologia</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Kulturoznawstwo</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel1">Informatyka społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Socjologia 2st</h3>
<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">E-gospodarka</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">Innowacje i interwencje społeczne</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel2">Multimedia i komunikacja społeczna</div></a>
</div>

<h3>Kulturoznawstwo 2st</h3>
<div id="kafel">
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Komunikacja wizualna i projektowanie graficzne</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Ochrona dóbr natury i kultury</div></a>
<a href="http://localhost/WH/"><div id="kafel3">Projektowanie graficzne w kulturze nowych mediów</div></a>
</div>

#kafel {

   font-size:15px;
   color: #358dd5;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
      }

#kafel1 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  display: table-cell !important;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;

}

#kafel1:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;

}

#kafel2 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;

}

#kafel2:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;
}

#kafel3 {
  width:183px;
  height:183px;
  margin-right:20px !important;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color:green;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  display: table-cell !important;
  border:10px solid white;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;

}

#kafel3:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#358dd5;
```

}

jsfiddle:- jsfiddle.net/6hcoejtn/2

Comment: jsfiddle:-  https://jsfiddle.net/6hcoejtn/2/

Comment: add that fiddle in your answer and also include what you did so op don't have to read or compare full code. Thank you

Comment: I have changed the #kafel {display:table; to display:flex;

Comment: yes i have checked that but m saying add that to your answer and that fiddle too so people who are having same issue can get the hint without reading whole code..got my point?